# Query for dedicated nvidia transfer queue

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've just started learning vulkan and read online about the queue system of NVIDIA with its 16 general purpose Queues and its single dedicated transfer queue.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to query for that specific queue in vulkan. (Of course, if it is not available, another one could be used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is!

It would have the TRANSFER_BIT set and none of the others.

E.g. like so: http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=638#queuefamilies

That information is obtained using `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties` command.

BTW: not that it is something specific to NVIDIA. My AMD exposes two specialized TRANSFER+SPARSE queues.